# Undefined behavior in sorting with comparator

Tags: c++, clang

I need to parse numbers from a string and sort vector in ascending range for the first number and, if first numbers equals, by second numbers in alphabetic order like strings:
`[1, 250; 2, 30; 4, 40; 1, 26]` -> `[1, 250; 1, 26; 2, 30; 4, 40]`.
As "250" < "26", array sorted like before.
There is algorithm:

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int sum_digits(int a);

string orderWeight()
{
    vector<pair<int, int> > weight_number;
    string str = "103 123 4444 99 2000 ";
    string Numbers = "1234567890";
    int Num;
    for (auto i_beg = str.cbegin(); i_beg < str.cend(); ++i_beg)
    {
        if (Numbers.find(*i_beg) != string::npos)
            for (auto i_end = i_beg + 1; i_end < str.cend(); ++i_end)
            {
                if (Numbers.find(*i_end) == string::npos)
                {
                    Num = stoi(string(i_beg, i_end));
                    weight_number.emplace_back(sum_digits(Num)/*This function count sum of digits*/, Num);
                    i_beg = i_end;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    sort(weight_number.begin(), weight_number.end(),
       [](const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) -> bool {
        if (a.first != b.first)
            return a.first < b.first;
        string s1 = to_string(a.second);
        string s2 = to_string(b.second);
        bool res = s1.compare(s2) < 0;
        return res;
    });

    string result;
    for (auto El: weight_number)
    {
        result += to_string(El.second) + " ";
    }
    result.pop_back();
    return result;
}

int sum_digits(int a)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (; a > 0; a /= 10)
    {
        sum += a % 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main ()
{
assert(orderWeight()=="2000 103 123 4444 99")
return 0;
}
```

On gcc all works good, but clang compiler throws an error:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==1==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffc35a59000 (pc 0x7f6029c2bb1f bp 0x000000001fff sp 0x7ffc35a562a8 T1)
==1==WARNING: invalid path to external symbolizer!
==1==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x7f6029c2bb1e  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x18eb1e)
    #1 0x7f602a60a137  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x13d137)
    #2 0x7f602a5f9432  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x12c432)
    #3 0x42be9d  (/workspace/test+0x42be9d)
    #4 0x42b9a2  (/workspace/test+0x42b9a2)
    #5 0x425660  (/workspace/test+0x425660)
    #6 0x4258b7  (/workspace/test+0x4258b7)
    #7 0x42838c  (/workspace/test+0x42838c)
    #8 0x426a9e  (/workspace/test+0x426a9e)
    #9 0x426622  (/workspace/test+0x426622)
    #10 0x4261db  (/workspace/test+0x4261db)
    #11 0x42b5a5  (/workspace/test+0x42b5a5)
    #12 0x42573d  (/workspace/test+0x42573d)
    #13 0x7f6029abeb96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #14 0x404679  (/workspace/test+0x404679)

==1==ABORTING
```

If I comment `if(..)`, or write `res=true`, or `s1="Something"`, or `s2 ="Something"` without `to_string(.second)` this error disappears. But the program works exactly contrariwise I need. I already search in a search engine without any result.

 What I should do to remove this error on clang compiler?

Comment: Make the parameters to your lambda function `const` references.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause UB. Can you show the rest of your code? The UB may be invoked somewhere else.

Comment: *but clang compiler throws an error* -- It isn't the compiler that is causing the error, it is your code.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkRansom - other than just general goodness, I don't see how adding const would address the OP's issue.

Comment: @selbie if the function was called with a temporary, that could result in undefined behavior if the parameter were modified in any way.  And undefined behavior is exactly what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: I add const's to pairs, but the error still present.

Comment: @Alexander That is still not a [mcve].  We should be able to take the code, and without making any changes, get it compile and produce the error.

Comment: [This is an example of a minimal, verifiable example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46a6f01d2fa3a92f).  You can take that code, not change a single line, not add a line, or remove a line, and it will compile and run.  The error cannot be duplicated with that code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I set a reproducible code. I am apologize if it bit more complicated, but I don't know what to push from the code.

Comment: @Alexander No, it doesn't reproduce, because it doesn't compile.  [main.cpp:7:1: error: 'string' does not name a type; did you mean 'stdin'?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e41994e64a58725f)

Comment: And [the code runs fine on clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b679558d3afa0a4a), once I fix all the compiler errors

Comment: @Alexander -- Take the code at the link I posted.  Do not change a single line in it.  Compile it.  Run it.  Does it run without error?  If it does run without error, then add to that code so that you reproduce your error.

Comment: @MarkRansom - if the comparator accepts non-`const` references, it *cannot* be called with a temporary.   There's no undefined behaviour - that would be a diagnosable error, since a temporary cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference.

Comment: @Peter the question is about deciphering what appears to be a compiler error.  In the grand tradition of C++ compilers I don't expect the error message to be straight-forward.  Anything that could generate any kind of error is fair game.

Comment: @MarkRansom - The OP incorrectly claims a compiler error.   The actual error described is a run time error.

Comment: I wouldn't say it compiler error, I want to say that is in my code error with this compiler. @PaulMcKenzie, I cannot modify code as I want, it is from kata [link]https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c6126177c9441a570000cc/train/cpp

Comment: This is the original code for solving this kata and I tested on my computer with gcc, that all works. But in kata's clang compiler it not work. https://codeshare.io/anZQmj

Comment: @Alexander - You might not call it a compiler error, at least now now, but when you originally posted the question (before you subsequently edited it) you described the error message as being from the compiler.    Members with sufficient rep here have visibility of the edit history, even if you don't.

Comment: @Peter, maybe I incorrectly formulated the proposal in original question, i'm sorry. I originally wanted to say that this is a mistake in MY code.

Comment: Does no one know exactly what error is in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe site [www.codewars.com](http://www.codewars.com) making something wrong as i wrote in comments because I also try it with clang compiler and there are no errors.

Thank you all for trying to help me with my question!